# Is there an interesting algorithm behind np.searchsorted()?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

The searchsorted() function is very useful for organizing data within numpy, and it scales particularly for large arrays.

Why is it so fast? Is it just that (similar to vectorizing code), we can have the code run directly in "C". But is it possible that I can get something similar with more basic functions within numpy? Can I write (what people who use matlab call) "vectorized code" to perform the operation of searchsorted?

Comment: The algorithm is basic, tt uses binary search, so it can scale logarithmically instead of linearly at the cost of sorting data up front. Vectorization doesn't play into this, although, the code is implemented at the C level I imagine. You can implement something similar using the `bisect` module, or writing your own bisection search algorithm (as millions of introductory CS students must do eventually...)

Comment: Note, vectorization generally only affects "constant factors", that is it isn't *algorithmically* more efficient than a python-level for-loop, it's just significantly faster, but it will scale the same.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but `searchsorted` is already vectorized. In `result = a.searchsorted(target)`, `a` and `target` can both be arrays and `result` will have the same shape as `target`. If you need something different, can you describe what you need.

Comment: @BiRico, I think my question has been answered, but I was looking for an explanation for what happens inside the searchsorted function, and if there is code that I can write within numpy/python that could rival its speed. (so that I can understand the algorithm that explains its speedup)

Answer (score 1):

Spyder (IPython console) and line magics are useful...

```
np.searchsorted??
Signature: np.searchsorted(a, v, side='left', sorter=None)
Source:   
@array_function_dispatch(_searchsorted_dispatcher)
def searchsorted(a, v, side='left', sorter=None):
    """
    Find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.
... huge snip
    This function uses the same algorithm as the builtin python `bisect.bisect_left`
    (``side='left'``) and `bisect.bisect_right` (``side='right'``) functions,
    which is also vectorized in the `v` argument.
... ditto    
    """
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'searchsorted', v, side=side, sorter=sorter)
File:      c:\...source path...\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Type:      function
```

So the search would be on the python side for bisect if the actual algorithm details are required.

Comment: So gathering what you said with the comments, the numpy code basically applies a binary search method in C, which explains its speedup relative to "vectorized" code that will (quickly) search through each element in the list.